# Perform actions while in inserting/editing in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm developing a simple CRUD using C#, WPF and MVVM. I'm using a DataGrid for navigation, Databounded Textboxes, a "New" button for Inserting, and the user can simply change the textbox values to change data and in the end click "Save" button.

Now, I can disable the DataGrid easily after click the "New" button, and reenable after the click on "Save" button.

But, what about edition? I want disable the DataGrid while editing, but I don't know how I do it in MVVM.

1. I do it in the View, and I look some "PropertyChanged" from Textboxes?
2. I do it in the ViewModel, and I look some "PropertyChanged" from the Entity properties (I implement INotifyPropertyChanged for my entities already)?
3. Another option?

Answer (score 1):

You can the textboxes read-only by default, and only enable them when the user enters `edit` or `create new` state.

BTW, you shouldn't be implementing CRUD interface when `DataGrid` supports that already.

Edit: code to help you visualize

**XAML**

```
<__CONTAINER__.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CrudTextBoxStyle"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
           TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EditMode}" Value="CreateNew">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EditMode}" Value="Edit">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</__CONTAINER__.Resources>


<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Records}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentRecord}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow" />

<Button Content="Create New" />
<Button Content="Edit" />
<Button Content="Save" />
<Button Content="Cancel" />

<TextBox Style="{StaticResource CrudTextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding CurrentRecord.TextProperty1}" />
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource CrudTextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding CurrentRecord.TextProperty2}" />
```

**code behind**

```
class CrudViewModel
{
    // you should use the full implementation with INPC
    public Record CurrentRecord { get; set; }
    public IList<Record> Records { get; set; }
    public EditMode EditMode { get; set; }

    private void CreateNewImpl()
    {
        CurrentRecord = new Record();
        EditMode = EditMode.CreateNew;
    }
    private void EditImpl()
    {
        EditMode = EditMode.Edit;
    }
    private void SaveImpl()
    {
        if (EditMode == EditMode.CreateNew)
        {
            Records.Add(CurrentRecord);
        }

        EditMode = EditMode.View;
    }
}

enum EditMode
{
    View, CreateNew, Edit
}
```

Comment: When you says "edit" or "create new" state, is from DbContext?

Comment: No. It should be an enum which you expose as a property from your viewmodel.

Comment: I understand you, but my questions is about that "Edit" button. Right now I'm not using an Edit button, the user can simply modify the textboxes and save, so I was thinking about detect changes in the Textboxes (or in the model, idk) in order to "change the state to edit mode". I will think in you solution of read-only Textboxes